# Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error

I am having an issue where I continually get the error:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146
```

I have created a script in the SQL directory of the module. Here is the script.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer = $startSetup();

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('hwcustomer/messages'))
    ->addColumn('message_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('subject', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Subject')
    ->addColumn('message', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Message')
    ->addColumn('reply', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Reply')
    ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Status')
    ->addColumn('original_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,array(
        'identity'  => true,
        'unsigned'  => true,
        'nullable'  => false,
        'primary'   => true,
        ), 'Id');

$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);

$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

I have set the version of the module back to the previous version in the core_resource table so when I refresh the page, it will create this table. But it still get this error after the version number is updated in the core_resource table.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: You are setting identity and primary options for 2 columns. I am not sure if Magento can handle multi column primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to fix this issue. In the following section:

```
->addColumn('original_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null,array(
    'identity'  => true,
    'unsigned'  => true,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'primary'   => true,
```

I took out the following lines.

```
    "identity'  => true,
```

and

```
    'primary'   => true,
```

Another way to fix it is to replace the entire function with raw SQL queries so it looks like this. Please note that I changed the message_id field to be called entity_id. I also added some new fields that I didn't realize I would need.

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer = $startSetup();
$installer->run("

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer_messages;  
CREATE TABLE customer_messages (
  `entity_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Subject',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `reply` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'reply',
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'Status',
  `original_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `original_customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    ");


$installer->endSetup();

?>
```

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is likely because you don't have a mapping of the resource name to the table name. Your `getTable` statement is attempting to access the table defined under `hwcustomer/messages`.

Ideally in your `etc/config.xml` file for your module you would have a config node that defines the entity:

```
<models>
    <hwcustomer>
        <class>YourCompany_Hwcustomer_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>hwcustomer_resource</resourceModel>
    </hwcustomer>
    <hwcustomer_resource>
        <class>YourCompany_Hwcustomer_Model_Entity</class>
        <entities>
            <messages>
                <table>hw_messages</table>
            </messages>
```

In this case `hwcustomer/messages` maps to the table `hw_messages`. In writing the SQL directly you likely helped avoid this issue because you're not using a resource locator to find the table name.